# How to Calculate and Draw Dimension Line (line with perpendicular end lines) in iOS using Core Graphics?

Tags: ios, math, drawing, geometry, core-graphics

I know how to draw simple lines using Core Graphics. I now need to draw a Dimension line for measurements. See the image below for an example of what I need to draw (in red). The top line would be easy, but drawing the perpendicular on a diagonal line will require some math that I'm having a difficult time figuring out right now.

Each main line will have (x,y) as a starting point and (x1,y1) as an ending point. I then need to draw the perpendicular lines that intersect at each of the points (x,y) and (x1,y1).

What is the math required to calculate the points for these perpendicular lines?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code computes a vector of length 1 that is perpendicular to
the line from `p = (x, y)` to `p1 = (x1, y1)`:

```
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(x, y);
CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(x1, y1);

// Vector from p to p1;
CGPoint diff = CGPointMake(p1.x - p.x, p1.y - p.y);
// Distance from p to p1:
CGFloat length = hypotf(diff.x, diff.y);
// Normalize difference vector to length 1:
diff.x /= length;
diff.y /= length;
// Compute perpendicular vector:
CGPoint perp = CGPointMake(-diff.y, diff.x);
```

Now you add and subtract a multiple of that perpendicular vector to the first point
to get the endpoints of the first marker line at `p`:

```
CGFloat markLength = 3.0; // Whatever you need ...
CGPoint a = CGPointMake(p.x + perp.x * markLength/2, p.y + perp.y * markLength/2);
CGPoint b = CGPointMake(p.x - perp.x * markLength/2, p.y - perp.y * markLength/2);
```

For the second marker line, just repeat the last calculation with `p1` instead of `p`.